# How can I split strings without worrying about mutable borrows?

Tags: rust

I'm currently trying to solve [this challenge](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/4) to learn Rust. I've created my own solution below:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    let req = ["byr", "iyr", "eyr", "hgt", "hcl", "ecl", "pid", "cid"];
    let mut res: u32 = 0;

    while stdin.read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap() > 0 {
        if buffer == "\n" {
            for r in req.iter() {    
                if set.contains(r) {
                    set.remove(r);
                }
            }

            if (set.len() == req.len()) || (set.len() == 7 && !set.contains("cid")) {
                res += 1;
            }
        } else {
            if buffer.ends_with('\n') {
                buffer.pop();
            }

            let inputs: Vec<&str> = buffer.split_whitespace().collect();

            for key_val in inputs {
                let kval: Vec<&str> = key_val.split(':').collect();
                
                set.insert(kval[0]);
            }
        }   
        
        buffer.clear();
    }

    println!("{}", res);
}
```

When I tried to compile it, the compiler outputs the error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `buffer` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

if (set.len() == req.len()) || (set.len() == 7 && !set.contains("cid")) {
   |                 --- immutable borrow later used here
...
28 |             let inputs: Vec<&str> = buffer.split_whitespace().collect();
   |                                     ------ immutable borrow occurs here
...
37 |         buffer.clear();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

I've solved other problems by using this kind of style before (using `&mut buffer` and `split` it somewhere) without getting this error.

Why does this error occur here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you already read this? https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html

Comment: @mkrieger1, yeah. But I don't get why `buffer.split_whitespace` is considered as `immutable borrow`.

Comment: It is an immutable borrow because it returns slices borrowed from the original `buffer`. As long as they live, it is considered borrowed.

Comment: @rodrigo, but I have declared `buffer` as mutable, shouldn't the borrow considered to be mutable as well?

Comment: No, `split_whitespace()` takes a `&self`, not a `&mut self`, so it borrows the buffer immutably, it does not matter if it is declared `mut` or not. But even if it were mutably borrowed, that would not help your code, because you cannot mutably borrow a value twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the type of your `set` variable. You can get it by writing a `set as ()` just after the `set.insert(...)` line. You'll see this error message:

```
non-primitive cast: `HashSet<&str>` as `()`
```

So you set holds references to `str`. But where do these references live. Well, all your `str` ultimately come from `buffer` so they are references to the contents of `buffer`. If you were allowed to do `buffer.clear()` all these references would become invalidated.

You have two basic options:

1. Keep all your lines in memory all the time so that your references in `set` are not invalidated. You could use `read
2. Store `String` instead of `&str` values in the `set`.

The easier solution is #2:

```
set.insert(kval[0].to_owned());
```

With that and a few other minor fixes, your algorithm will compile ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=adab1a2624b2986fde9b7eb908645b0f)).

Option #1 would require to read the whole stdin into a variable and then iterate over the lines:

```
    use std::io::Read;
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut input = String::new();
    stdin.read_to_string(&mut input).unwrap();
    for buffer in input.lines() {
       ...
    }
```

Now `buffer` is a `&str` instead of a `String`, but the lifetime of the values in `set` will be that of `input` that is outside of the loop. You would need a few minor fixes, particularly with the end-of-line checks.

Comment: Thanks, but why `String` though? Can I use `&str` instead?

Comment: @CristopherNamchee: Do you mean as a type in the `set`? Because `&str` is a borrowed type, by definition, because it is a reference, while a `String` is not. In order for a (non `'static`) `&str` to exist there must be a borrowed value somewhere.